# NPM: change registry in package-lock.json

Tags: node.js, npm, package-lock.json, npm-registry

For security reason, I need a specific registry, but in the `package-lock.json` I still keep the `https://registry.npmjs.org/`

Is there any way to force it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Override registry for installed packages in package-lock.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62439074/override-registry-for-installed-packages-in-package-lock-json)

Answer (score -4):

Best way to do so, use a `.npmrc` and also use `npm ci` to avoid `package-lock.json` modification.