# Override registry for installed packages in package-lock.json

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-registry

I have a large, existing `package-lock.json` and a lot of dependencies that have been resolved via http://registry.npmjs.org/.

e.g.

```
{
  "name": "my-package",
  "version": "1.2.3",
  "lockfileVersion": 1,
  "requires": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": {
      "version": "7.7.4",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@babel/cli/-/cli-7.7.4.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-O7mmzaWdm+VabWQmxuM8hqNrWGGihN83KfhPUzp2lAW4kzIMwBxujXkZbD4fMwKMYY9FXTbDvXsJqU+5XHXi4A==",
      "dev": true,
      "requires": {
        "chokidar": "^2.1.8",
        "commander": "^4.0.1",
        "convert-source-map": "^1.1.0",
        "fs-readdir-recursive": "^1.1.0",
        "glob": "^7.0.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.13",
        "make-dir": "^2.1.0",
        "slash": "^2.0.0",
        "source-map": "^0.5.0"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "commander": {
          "version": "4.0.1",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/commander/-/commander-4.0.1.tgz",
          "integrity": "sha512-IPF4ouhCP+qdlcmCedhxX4xiGBPyigb8v5NeUp+0LyhwLgxMqyp3S0vl7TAPfS/hiP7FC3caI/PB9lTmP8r1NA==",
          "dev": true
        },
        "make-dir": {
          "version": "2.1.0",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/make-dir/-/make-dir-2.1.0.tgz",
          "integrity": "sha512-LS9X+dc8KLxXCb8dni79fLIIUA5VyZoyjSMCwTluaXA0o27cCK0bhXkpgw+sTXVpPy/lSO57ilRixqk0vDmtRA==",
          "dev": true,
          "requires": {
            "pify": "^4.0.1",
            "semver": "^5.6.0"
          }
        },
        "pify": {
          "version": "4.0.1",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/pify/-/pify-4.0.1.tgz",
          "integrity": "sha512-uB80kBFb/tfd68bVleG9T5GGsGPjJrLAUpR5PZIrhBnIaRTQRjqdJSsIKkOP6OAIFbj7GOrcudc5pNjZ+geV2g==",
          "dev": true
        },
        "source-map": {
          "version": "0.5.7",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/source-map/-/source-map-0.5.7.tgz",
          "integrity": "sha1-igOdLRAh0i0eoUyA2OpGi6LvP8w=",
          "dev": true
        }
      }
    },
    ...
```

I have my registry configured to be an NPM Enterprise installation that hosts proprietary NPM packages and mirrors the public NPM registry.

```
registry = "https://custom.registry.tld/path/npm/npm-aggregate"
```

This works for newly installed packages, but many existing packages still point to the public NPM registry. I tried overwriting the package-lock.json using `npm i` or `npm i --package-lock-only`.

How can I force NPM to use my Enterprise NPM registry and write the correct `resolved` URLs to `package-lock.json`? I probably could just "find and replace", but I want to make sure that NPM is resolving dependencies correctly.

Comment: We've had the same issue not a while back. What we end up doing is changing the registry url manually, removing `node_modules` and running `npm i` again to check that it works.

Comment: I just think `package-lock.json` has been designed to hardcode the registry. Could it be to avoid package collision if 2 registries own 2 different packages with the same name?
It bother me for the exact same reason as you. I didn't find a solution so far

Comment: Wouldn't a simple search & replace in `package-lock.json` be enough?

Answer (score 12):

I am running `npm -v` 6.14.15

I simply changed the registry entries manually in the  `package-lock.json` and deleted the `node_modules` folder, then ran an `npm i` to solve this issue.

Some solutions that didn't work for me:

When I tried to change the registry simply using the npm CLI by clearing the cache `npm cache clear --force`, and `npm i --registry` none of this worked. The registry didn't change at all, and in fact was reverted after running `npm i` in any form.

I then tried to remove the `package-lock.json` and `node_modules` and ran an install. This caused a lot of versions in my package-lock.json to change and caused my particular projects builds to fail.

I found that the steps I followed got what I wanted although it may not be a part of best practices with npm.

Comment: What's the point to have a lock file, if you don't use it?

if you run `npm i`, you will update the lock file
if you run `npm ci`, you will use the lock file

Comment: @Gabriel the request here is to use the new repository without changing the version numbers. It appears npm does not provide any solution for that, so manually updating the `package-lock.json` appears to be the only solution.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, the `package-lock.json` file is meant to hardcode the registry of each package. It is intended.

We could imagine a future option in NPM to force the registry, in combination with an integrity check to make sure the packages are identical. (Feel free to send a feature request to the core team)

As of today, npm does not cover this use case. You are forced to ignore the `package-lock.json` to bypass this limitation.

(as of today, the latest version of NPM is 8.13.2)

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to force the "resolved" and "integrity" fields to be regenerated by:

- Edit package-lock.json and remove all the "resolved" and "integrity" properties.
- Clear npm cache :`npm cache clean --force`
- Run `npm install`

You should now have a package-lock.json with fresh resolved and integrity properties yet all the dependencies version should be unchanged.

Comment: Deletion of node_modules folder needs to be there also, else npm install won't do much if all were up to date.

Comment: I'm using node v18.19.0 and npm 10.2.3, the dependency can be installed properly, but the `resolved` and `integrity` properties won't be regenerated.

Answer (score 3):

Overriding the registry will not replace existing `"resolved": "https://xxx..."` entries in the `package-lock.json`.

If this one is wrong from a previous creation, you have to delete it, then run again your `npm i`. It will create a fresh one with the registry previously configured.

Comment: I initially downvoted this answer, but I changed my mind. Unfortunately, it is too late to change my vote.

Comment: The problem from deleting the file is that you will lose the version numbers that you initially had, so it will do more than changing the URL’s.

Answer (score 0):

1. Find/replace registry in package-lock
2. Delete node_modules
3. Verify `npm install` works