# npm install changed the package-lock resolved for some packages from registry.npmjs.org to registry.yarnpkg.com

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg, package-lock.json

I am using npm 6

```
❯ npm -v
6.14.11
```

and the registry is set to

```
❯ npm config get registry
https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

```
❯ cat  ~/.npmrc
registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

removing the `package-lock.json`(should not be needed) file and running `npm install`
generates some values that load from `yarnpkg` registry

example

```
"deep-is": {
      "version": "0.1.3",
      "resolved": "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/deep-is/-/deep-is-0.1.3.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha1-s2nW+128E+7PUk+RsHD+7cNXzzQ=",
      "dev": true
    },
```

why is that? and why is my registry preference not respected?

Comment: is it possible they're cached?  Have you tried `npm cache clear --force` and then see what happens?

Comment: nuking everything: cache, node_modules, package-lock.json 
did produce a new valid package-lock.json containing only npmjs.org resolves, but so many changes to the package-lock file that reviewing the dependencies is hard

that solved my problem, @joe

Comment: You ask "why" but the accepted answer is answering with a fix - which would be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/62439074/4722345

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am running `npm -v` 6.14.15

Perhaps you didn't remove the `node_modules` folder before doing an install? Apparently the registry value from `node_modules` will override anything from the `package-lock.json`.

You should change the registry values inside of the `package-lock.json`, delete `node_modules` folder, and then do an `npm i`.

Answer (score 1):

npm install respects the package-lock. It won't update it unless you're adding/updating a package (which you've done in the past after configuring the new registry, resulting in some entries with the new registry).

If you're interested in updating your package-lock to use the new registry for all deps, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62439074/4722345).