# How to replace the registry from package-lock.json to a new one?

Tags: npm, package.json

Currently, the package registry in the `package-lock.json` is `http://registry.npm.taobao.org/`.

`package-lock.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "webpack",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "lockfileVersion": 1,
  "requires": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/clean-webpack-plugin": {
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "resolved": "http://registry.npm.taobao.org/@types/clean-webpack-plugin/download/@types/clean-webpack-plugin-0.1.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha1-xJillaQXSwoxPOQt5+UldcEi9aQ=",
      "dev": true,
      "requires": {
        "@types/webpack": "*"
      }
    },
    "@types/node": {
      "version": "9.4.0",
      "resolved": "http://registry.npm.taobao.org/@types/node/download/@types/node-9.4.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha1-uFoLzx4cyE60kBt+lpZq7cbweNE=",
      "dev": true
    },
    "@types/strip-bom": {
      "version": "3.0.0",
      "resolved": "http://registry.npm.taobao.org/@types/strip-bom/download/@types/strip-bom-3.0.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha1-FKjsOVbC6B7bdSB5CuzyHCkK69I=",
      "dev": true
    },
    // ...others
}
```

I want to replace all registries with the npm official registry `https://registry.npmjs.org/` or any specific registry. Keep using the same versions of packages.

How can I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Override registry for installed packages in package-lock.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62439074/override-registry-for-installed-packages-in-package-lock-json)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution from [issue](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/2566#issuecomment-278635721) of yarn.

Before replacing the registries, let's check how many registries need to be replaced, I will check the number of `taobao` words to determine.

```sh
☁  v4 [master] ⚡  grep -o 'taobao' package-lock.json | wc -l
    1180
```

Since some registries' pattern like this:

```json
"resolved": "https://registry.npm.taobao.org/@hapi/joi/download/@hapi/joi-15.1.1.tgz?cache=0&sync_timestamp=1603524515155&other_urls=https%3A%2F%2Fregistry.npm.taobao.org%2F%40hapi%2Fjoi%2Fdownload%2F%40hapi%2Fjoi-15.1.1.tgz",
```

The `other_urls` query string contains the url address of the `taobao` registry. The `//` symbol for the `https` protocol is escaped, so I will just replace `registry.npm.taobao.org` instead of `https://registry.npm.taobao.org`.

Besides, I removed the old `node_modules` using `rm -rf node_modules`, later, I will install node modules after replacing the registry with the new one, re-run `npm install` and run my application to check if it works.

Now, replace the registry using the below Linux command:

```sh
sed -i -e "s#registry.npm.taobao.org#registry.npmjs.org#g" package-lock.json
```

Check:

```sh
☁  v4 [master] ⚡  grep -o 'taobao' package-lock.json | wc -l                                  
       0
☁  v4 [master] ⚡  grep -o 'npmjs' package-lock.json | wc -l
    1180
```

After re-install the node modules with the new registries, my project generated by `create-react-app` tool works fine.

Comment: Did you encounter error about "npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY npm ERR! sha1-xOu8KJ85kaAo1EdRy90RkYsXkQw= integrity checksum failed when using sha1: wanted sha1-xOu8KJ85kaAo1EdRy90RkYsXkQw= but got sha512-RrERod97Dnwqq49WNz8qo66ps0swYZDSb6rM57kN2J+aoyEAJfZ6bMx0sx/F9TIEX0xthPGCmeyiam/jXif0eA== sha1-zUTECrB6DHo23F6Zqs4eyk7CaQw=. (3446 bytes)" during the re-installation? I got stuck on it.

Comment: @JohnXiao Replace `wanted` integrity with `already acquired ` integrity as error message shows