# Issues changing npm registry

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package-lock.json

I have a Vue 2.7 project with vuetify installed. First, I install dependencies using a custom local npm registry, which is a proxy to npm default, now the project is growing and I'm using git actions to deploy for a development server, or at least I'm trying to.

When GitHub actions try to `npm install` it uses package-lock.json with my registry configured, and of course can't find it, if I delete my package-lock.json or set package-lock to false before install, it returns a lot of warns and error since packages dependencies are outdated.(this happens even when I use specific versions on package.json)

My questions are.

How can I update the npm registry for all my package-lock.json tree of dependencies in order to maintain the right version for every one of them?

Is there any other solution?

Comment: TLDR: find/replace in package-lock, delete node_modules, verify npm install works.

Comment: This post has the same unresolved problem, if replace, when npm i, all specific dependencies version are lost and build crash.

Comment: What do you mean deps versions are lost? Same deps, diff registry

Comment: Yes, I meant packages specific dependencies, I can only control mine.

Comment: Can you try out [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74134709/4722345) on the other question and share evidence of what you're describing?

Comment: @JBallin It works, I tested replacing before, but also had the no package lock option, this is the way to go. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my [answer on a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74134709/4722345):

> 1. Find/replace registry in package-lock
> 2. Delete node_modules
> 3. Verify `npm install` works